# kmm supend fun throw exception in swift

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

There is a suspend fun in the common code

```
class HttpClientEngine22 {

    suspend fun printer1() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {

        }
    }
}
```

when the suspend funs called from swift , on android everything is working but the issue on swfit code , I have no idea about the exception because kmm debug is almost impossible

```
let httpClientEngine22 = HttpClientEngine22()
httpClientEngine22.printer1{
    e in
}
    



    0x10938b627 <+55>: jmp    0x10938b629               ; <+57> at CoroutineExceptionHandlerImpl.kt
    0x10938b629 <+57>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rax
    0x10938b62d <+61>: movq   (%rax), %rdi
    0x10938b630 <+64>: callq  0x1092ad5d0               ; Kotlin_processUnhandledException
->  0x10938b635 <+69>: jmp    0x10938b637               ; <+71> at CoroutineExceptionHandlerImpl.kt:14:2
```

sometimes

```
Kotlin_ObjCExport_runCompletionFailure
 Kotlin_ObjCExport_trapOnUndeclaredException
```

Comment: How does `printer1` differ from `printer2`, only dispatcher? Can you add logs to `printer1` to see what happens? Does `printer1` contain UI code?

Comment: @CoolMind the are the same issue